# Python - Iterate thru month dates and print a custom output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently unsure on the logic to be used for the below problem and new to programming as well.(Currently learning python)

Trying to iterate thru every date for a given month - say 05/01 -- 05/31 and print it out in the below format.

[image]

Monday thru Friday dates are to be printed separately.
Saturday & Sunday dates are to be printed separately.

If the month starts on say Friday - 05/01/2020, ouput should be like
[image]
as, its the last weekday of that week.

For the month of April 2020, output would be like below, as April month's 1st week started on Wednesday.

[image]

I managed to comeup with the below try, but not sure how to proceed further.

```
import sys
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

year = int(sys.argv[1])
month = int(sys.argv[2])
st_dt = int(sys.argv[3])
en_dt = int(sys.argv[4])

first_date = datetime(year, month, st_dt).date()
get_first_day = datetime(year, month, st_dt).isoweekday()

def daterange(startDate, endDate, delta=timedelta(days=1)):
    currentDate = startDate
    while currentDate <= endDate:
        yield currentDate
        currentDate += delta

for date in daterange(date(year, month, st_dt), date(year, month, en_dt), delta=timedelta(days=1)):
     print(date)


  date.py 2020 5 1 31 # script
```

Came up with a standalone 'if loop' and as i said before,  not sure how to construct the bigger picture :(

```
if get_first_day == 1:
        #print("Monday")
        sec_d =  first_date + timedelta(days=4)
elif get_first_day == 2:
        sec_d = first_date + timedelta(days=3)
elif get_first_day == 3:
        sec_d = first_date + timedelta(days=2)
elif get_first_day == 4:
        sec_d = first_date + timedelta(days=2)
elif get_first_day == 5:
        sec_d = first_date
        #print("Friday")
else:
        pass

print(f"Second date:{sec_d} ") -- which gave  -- > Second date:2020-05-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the dates in a dictionary, dictionary key is tuple of calendar week and type of day (weekend, day of the week).

Each day is saved by in the `allDays` dictionary, grouped by the combination of weeknum and type of day as key:

```
 ('18', 'weekend'): [datetime.date(2020, 5, 2), datetime.date(2020, 5, 3)],
 ('18', 'working'): [datetime.date(2020, 5, 1)],
 ('19', 'weekend'): [datetime.date(2020, 5, 9), datetime.date(2020, 5, 10)],
 ('19', 'working'): [datetime.date(2020, 5, 4), ...
```

So you just need to take out the fist and last item of each dict item:

```
import sys
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

year, month, st_dt, en_dt = 2020, 5, 1, 31

first_date = datetime(year, month, st_dt).date()
get_first_day = datetime(year, month, st_dt).isoweekday()

def daterange(startDate, endDate, delta=timedelta(days=1)):
    currentDate = startDate
    while currentDate <= endDate:
        yield currentDate
        currentDate += delta

allDays = {}
_lastDayType = None
for dte in daterange(date(year, month, st_dt), date(year, month, en_dt), delta=timedelta(days=1)):
    if 0 <= dte.weekday() < 5:
        _dayType = 'working'
    else:
        _dayType = 'weekend'

    _weeknum = dte.strftime("%V")  # number of calendar week
    _key = (_weeknum, _dayType)
    if _key not in allDays:        # create an empty list if unique key doesnt exist
        allDays[_key] = []
    allDays[_key].append(dte)      # add the dates ...

for k,v in allDays.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        first, last = v[0], v[0]
    else:
        first, last = v[0], v[-1]
    print("%s >> %s" % (first, last))
```

Output:

```
2020-05-01 >> 2020-05-01
2020-05-02 >> 2020-05-03
2020-05-04 >> 2020-05-08
2020-05-09 >> 2020-05-10
2020-05-11 >> 2020-05-15
2020-05-16 >> 2020-05-17
2020-05-18 >> 2020-05-22
2020-05-23 >> 2020-05-24
2020-05-25 >> 2020-05-29
2020-05-30 >> 2020-05-31
```

Comment: That was so fast ! :) THanks !!!!

I'm kind of lost with the below logic

    `_weeknum = dte.strftime("%V")
    _key = (_weeknum, _dayType)
    if _key not in allDays:
        allDays[_key] = []
    allDays[_key].append(dte)`

Could you kindly explain that.

Comment: I'm trying to add an addtional functionality to check if a date in the given date range is national holiday, print "NH" and that corresponding date.
 Ex: 2020-05-04 & 2020-05-14 are national holidays and that date alone should be printed like

`NH 5/4/2020 5/4/2020
......
NH  5/14/2020 5/14/2020`

I tried:

`ph = []
for d in public_holiday:
    ph.append(date(year, month, int(d)))

.....

for k,v in allDays.items():
    week_end = ''
    gh = ''
   ........
    elif v in ph:
        print("NH")
    else:
        first, last = v[0], v[-1]`

Comment: SHould I raise it a separate question

Comment: ph array's ouput is `[datetime.date(2020, 5, 4), datetime.date(2020, 5, 14)]`

Comment: Yes, make a new question.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your time here :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176391/check-list-item-is-present-in-dictionary

Comment: Tried multiple options nothing worked. Am i using the data type incorrectly ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176391/check-list-item-is-present-in-dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215247/discussion-between-rookie1999-and-maurice-meyer).